# Why only one Mega Evolution?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, pokemon-sixth-generation

I've been playing Pokemon X for a while now, and about a month ago I caught myself a Mewtwo (score!) after I caught it, I found a Mewtwonite X. I decided to put Mewtwo in my party, alongside my Delphox, Xerneas, Raichu, Talonflame and Blastoise, and that's when a guy challenged me to a battle. I thrashed him (of course) but I found it strange that after I Mega Evolved my Blastoise, I couldn't Mega Evolve my Mewtwo during the same battle... Anybody know why this is?

Answer (score 13):

It's a built-in game mechanic. Per the [wiki](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mega_Evolution):

> Once per battle, only a single Pokémon for each Trainer may Mega Evolve. Switching the Mega Evolved Pokémon out will not dissolve a Mega Evolution. A Mega Evolved Pokémon can only revert back to its original state upon fainting or the conclusion of the battle. If a Mega Evolved Pokémon faints, but is later revived, that Pokémon cannot obtain a Mega Evolved state again for the remaining duration of the battle.

Comment: Beat me by 9 seconds. With an almost identical post. Same quote and everything. :)

Comment: Ha well ok that sucks... But thanks anyway guys! :D